# Destructuring Assignment Variables as Global Constants

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I have bunch of functions declared across my modules, which I would like to use as   global constants for all my codebase.

Now these functions declared as local constants:

```
const { function1, function2, function3, ..., functionN } = require('./my-module-1')
const { functionA, functionB, functionC, ..., functionN } = require('./my-module-2')
```

Is there shorter way to convert these function to globals instead of:

```
function1 = require('./my-module-1').function1
function2 = require('./my-module-1').function2
function3 = require('./my-module-1').function3
functionN = require('./my-module-1').functionN

functionA = require('./my-module-2').functionA
functionB = require('./my-module-2').functionB
functionC = require('./my-module-2').functionC
functionN = require('./my-module-2').functionN
```

I've tried just removing `const` keyword as well as added brackets around the destructuring assignment  but both caused syntax error

```
{ function1, function2, function3, ..., functionN } = require('./my-module-1')
{ functionA, functionB, functionC, ..., functionN } = require('./my-module-2')

({ function1, function2, function3, ..., functionN } = require('./my-module-1'))
({ functionA, functionB, functionC, ..., functionN } = require('./my-module-2'))
```

Comment: I can't understand. Do you want global variables or destructring technic?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out can i use  destructring technic to assign global variables

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion,

```
global.modules = require('sample-package'); // get all modules and set it to global object

let { module1 } = global.modules; // where you want use this

let { module2 } = global.modules; // where you want use this
```